# Ubuntu 20.04 On startup is showing command/info on login screen

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-20.04

Showing weird information/command at login. This is a local Ubuntu installation in a virtual box.

[image: ScreenShot View]

How can I fix this?

Comment: try using tty2 ...

Comment: thanks @jsotola 
I can connect to it using ssh but this is weird and I want to know if I could fix it. It's not critical but not normal.

Comment: try posting at https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: could be a startup script that contains a `verbose` command-line option ... could also be an incorrect sequence in startup ... `cloud-init` starting after `tty`